# Show/hide div on click using jQuery to create a "click menu"

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and need some help to show and hide a div on click. Basically I need to show a div (containing a small menu) once the user click on a link, and as soon as the user click on a link inside the div just shown. Or clicks outside the div I need to hide the div again.my HTML looks something like this (I'll exist in many places on the page).

```
<a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
<div class="menu-content" style="display: none; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; background-color: White;padding: 5px;">
 <div><a href="#">Menu option 1</a></div>
 <div><a href="#">Menu option 2</a></div>
</div>
```

I also have a div that wraps the whole page that I thought I'd set another click-event on to hide the div (to catch clicks outside of the actual menu).

Is this the right approach for solving this and how do I then remove the handlers on the wrapper div etc, etc. What else should I think of to get this right (if it it's the right approach that is)?

***Update:*** Based on the accepted answer below I added this to solve it

```
//Need to return false here, otherwise the event will bubble up and trigger the hide on body
$('.menu').click(function() { $('.menu-content').hide();$(this).next().show();return false; });
$('body, .menu-content a').click(function() { $('.menu-content').hide();});
$('.menu-content a').click(function() { alert($(this)); });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
html:

<a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
<div class='a_menu' style="display: none; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; background-color: White;padding: 5px;">
 <div><a href="#">Menu option 1</a></div>
 <div><a href="#">Menu option 2</a></div>
</div>

script:

$('.menu').click(function() { $(this).next('.a_menu').show(); });
$('body, .a_menu a').click(function() { $('.a_menu').hide(); });
```

I'd prolly replace the < A > tags with SPANS instead styled with 'cursor:pointer'

Comment: This will not work when I have it in multiple places within the page

Comment: mighta helped if you'd said that in your Q - you can refine the code i supplied with context and filters on selectors to handle ALL menus on your page

Comment: @Scott: I did ... "I'll exist in many places on the page". And in you code you only hide the menu on a click on the actual link ... Not outside of the menu.

Comment: yeah ok, i didn't realize a non-precise and fully tested answer that you couldn't use as a starting point was going to lose me reputation. I hope you're happier with the edit. good luck

Comment: the code i provided btw will hide ALL menus on any click on document body you can add your wrapper div to the list as well if you want

Comment: @Scott. Removed the down vote. Didn't realize it made you loose rep. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question and answers above, I was able to simplify the jquery code to get something closer to what I needed.  The HTML is ugly, and there's a full menu bar in here to put the drop down menu in context.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
#menu {
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#menu a,#menu span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 28px;
  background: #34579D;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 8px 15px 0px 15px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu .drop-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 31px;
}

#menu li ul li {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  //Need to return false here, otherwise the event will bubble up and trigger the hide on body
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drop-menu').click(function() {
      $('.drop-menu-content').toggle();
      return false;
    });
    $('body, .drop-menu-content span').click(function() {
      $('.drop-menu-content').hide();
    });
  });
  //]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" class="first">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/order_report.html" class="value">Order Computer Calculated Value Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="/php/order_appraisal.php">Order An Appraisal</a></li>
      <li class="current_page_item"><span class="drop-menu">Sample Reports</span>
        <ul class="drop-menu-content">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="/documents/value_check.pdf">Computer Calculated Report ($20)</a></li> <br />
          <li><a target="_blank" href="/documents/desktop.pdf">Computer Desk Top Appraisal ($45)</a></li> <br />
          <li><a target="_blank" href="/documents/exterior.pdf">Desk Top/Drive by Appraisal ($95)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/FAQ.html">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="/php/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="menu-content">
        <ul>
          <a href="/php/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have had issue with bcz i was not return false: this perfect answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [suckerfish](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns) and [listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/). What you trying to achieve may be solvable by CSS only. In addition you'll have gained some insight on how to do your navigation in a more semantic way.

Then you can dive into jQuery for stuff that cannot be done in plain HTML+CSS.

Comment: Nice articles but it's not at all what I'm looking for. Don't handle click and uses standard javascript to start with ...

Comment: The script simply fixes IE6's inability to :hover on anything other than a's.